# Check if native element exist or not in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this checkbox

```
  <input #optionA class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="answer" value="opt_a" />

  <input #optionB class="form-check-input" *ngIf="some condition" type="checkbox" name="answer" value="opt_b" />
```

in `ts file`

```
 @ViewChild("optionA") optionA : ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("optionB") optionB: ElementRef;

method()
{
  this.optionA.nativeElement ? console.log(this.optionA.nativeElement.checked) : '';
  this.optionB.nativeElement ? console.log(this.optionB.nativeElement.checked) : '';
```

getting error if nativeElement not available in this case `optionB` checkbox not generated is there anyway to check if the element exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optionA` / `optionB` are probably undefined. Check for them.